# ng lint command - How can I execute it on only one typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript, lint

I am using "**ng lint**" command from the latest **'angular cli'**.

Is it possible to run this command on only one typescript file instead of running on all the typescript files in the entire project ?

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 28):

For 10.1.7+ versions of angular cli use `--lint-file-patterns`

```
ng lint --lint-file-patterns src/app/app.component.ts
```

Comment: To clarify, this is for v10.1.7. and above. I am still on version 10.1.1 and had to use the `--files` switch as per one of the other answers.

Comment: You can lint all files in a specified folder using e.g. `ng lint --lint-file-patterns src/app/`

Answer (score 23):

As of Angular CLI version 8, you can lint a single file with

`ng lint --files src/app/app.component.ts`

Comment: Not sure when and if `--files` option was removed from angular cli. I'm using cli v10.1.7, and the option is no longer available. Instead I used `--lint-file-patterns`

Comment: I agree with @philipyoo, --files are not working with angular cli latest versions like 11 or 12.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is still valid for my current version (10.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

An easy workaround:
`ng lint | grep nameofyourfile`?

Comment: OP just wants a single file linted, while this still lints the entire project

Answer (score -1):

I know I am late to the party but someone else could benefit from this.
We face the same issue and to solve this I have created a package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lintone-cli

It is fairly simple package - you just need to pass command 
`lintone file name <file-name>`

and it will display lint error associated to that file